# Problems scraping data from a webpage that takes time to load

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape data from a webpage as part of practice, but it seems the way the webpage is set up is frustrating some of my efforts. Basically, I think the webpage takes a while to load the features I'm interested in and because of that, when I run the code to extract the data I want, it fails. Here's the webpage: https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/ExchRateByCurrency.asp

I noticed that the table section takes a while to load even when I inspect the source code.

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests import get

html = get("https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/ExchRateByCurrency.asp").text

html = bs(html,"lxml")
html = html.find("div",id="ContentTextinner")
```

Now if I run this `html.tbody`, here's my output:
[image]

By contrast, the website itself, once it's done loading, clearly has plenty within the section:

[image]

Upon reloading the webpage with the inspect view on, I found that the source code itself didn't load completely until a second or so had passed. I figured this might be why `html.tbody` shows up as empty even when, in the the fully loaded page, its chock-full of valuable information. I'd like some advice on how to solve this please?

Comment: I haven't used bs4, but can you not have a function in your code which waits, until the dom element with id "exTable" loads?, and then do what ever you want?
Also, check if the URL is rendering the required table, using AJAX, which they are delaying after page load, to reduce page load time?

Comment: @anuraagtummanapally I don't know how to do that. If you could point me in the relevant direction I would be immensely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like `selenium` to achieve this.

For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/ExchRateByCurrency.asp")

html = driver.page_source
print(html.find("div",id="ContentTextinner"))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that but it's giving me this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'page_source'`. Any ideas?

Comment: @AbubakarPopoola Sorry about that, I have edited my code. You shouldn't receive that error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
import requests as r

res = r.get('https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/outputExchangeRateJSN.asp')
if res.status_code == 200:
    data = res.json()
    # Do something with the data
else:
    print(f"Error: {res.status_code}")
```

You'll get the data as `JSON` and extract what you need from there.

This is because a request is made dynamically to fill the body of the page, that's why you couldn't find the content from first.

As you could as well, just use this link to download it as `CSV` file with all the content: [CSV_File](https://www.cbn.gov.ng/Functions/export.asp?tablename=exchange)

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I invite you to also check my edit.

Comment: @b14d35 I have edited the code. 1) the http status code is checked 2) I let request build the dict for me

Comment: @balderman I tried it. It's splendid, but how did you know to use that kind of link? After all, it's different from mine. I knew of the csv download available as well, but this is more for practicing my scraping and data manipulation skills. There's another site I want to scrape in a similar manner, but I don't think such a link exists. Even if it is I'd like to know how to resolve this issue without it.

Comment: I usually open the network tab in chrome console and check XHR requests ans see what kind of data it sends and the results it gets, if it's what I'm looking for, I'll use that.

Comment: The link was found by @b14d35 - I just modified the code in order to make it safer.

Comment: @b14d35 That''s literal magic. Thanks so much for the hint.